# React JSX, How to write complex condition and for loop in html of JSX?

Tags: reactjs

I have render method that required to execute code like below.
And I want to render nested for loop with if-else condition in JSX code.

How to coding in JSX like the concept code below.?

My purpose of coding is :

```js
class Step4Com extends Component<any, any>
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render()
    {
        const products = this.state.products;
        return <div>
            for(let pro of ) {
            <div key={pro.id}>
                if(pro.typex=='has_variant' && pro.type_code=='xccc') {
                    for(let variant of pro.variants){
                        <div key={pro + '_' + variant.id}>
                            <div className="text-ac">
                            {pro.name + ' : ' + variant.name}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
            }
        </div>;
    }
}
export default  Step4Com;
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4317297)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do, hope it helps.

```
import React from 'react';

const Products = ({ pro }) => {
    const children = [];
    if (pro.typex === 'has_variant' && pro.type_code === 'xccc') {
        for (let variant of pro.variants) {
            children.push(
                <div key={pro + '_' + variant.id}>
                    <div className="text-ac">
                    {pro.name + ' : ' + variant.name}
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    return children;
}

class Step4Com extends Component<any, any> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const products = this.state.products;
        return (
            <div>
              {
                products.map(product => <div key={product.id}><Products pro={product} /></div>)
              }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default  Step4Com;
```